# Is it possible to exclude specific tags from "Community Digest" E-Mail?

Tags: support, email, ignored-tags, community-digests

While I think the idea of "xxx Stack Exchange Community Digest" is great and I subscribed to one, I believe it does not take my ignored tags into account.

I assumed that ignoring the specific tags would also reduce the amount of posts I see with that tag (hopefully completely) in the community digest, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever. Is such feature available, and if yes, how can I enable it?

<del><sub><sup>*P.S. Since I'm assuming that this feature is in fact, not available, I'm also tagging this with "feature-request" as I believe it would be a great addition*</sup></sub></del>